# changing multiple states in react js useState() hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

So I was wondering what actually happens when I change more than one state in a handler function. Will they both get updated **simultaneously** or they will be executed **one after another**.

```
const [x, setX] = useState(0)
const [y, setY] = useState(0)

const handlerFunction = () => {
  setX(x+1)
  setY(y+1)
}
```

Also what If one state depend on others?

```
const handlerFunction = () => {
  setX(x+1)
  setY(x+1)
}
```

or what if

```
const [x, setX] = useState(0)
const [y, setY] = useState(x)

const handlerFunction = () => {
  setX(x+1)
  setY(y+1)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing ever runs simultaneously in JavaScript*, so the state updates occur one after the other. But since they're both done asynchronously, you won't see `x` or `y` update until the next render, so it will appear simultaneous from your perspective.

So in all three cases above, the final values for `x` and `y` after calling `handlerFunction()` once will be 1 and 1.

Also note that because `x` and `y` are simply variables, their values *can't* change synchronously anyway, which is why you only see their values update in the next render.

Just so you're aware though, it's good practice to use [functional updates](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates) when your state changes rely on the previous state:

```
const handlerFunction = () => {
  setX(x => x + 1)
  setY(y => y + 1)
}
```

This ensures that each update is an [atomic operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linearizability#High-level_atomic_operations).

<sub>*Unless you're dealing with worker threads</sub>

Answer (score 2):

https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/14259

> React batches state updates if they're triggered from within a React-based event

So if you call the handler from a `onClick`, `onChange`, `onBlur`... React will apply the multiple updates **simultaneously**. If you call the handler from a `Promise` or a `setTimeout`, the updates will be called **separately**.

If a state variable depends of another, I suggest to group them into an object like below :

```
const [obj, setObj] = useState(() => ({x: 0, y: 0}));

const handlerFunction = () => {
  setObj(prevObj => {
    const newVal = prevObj.x + 1;
    return {x: newVal, y: newVal};
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting a state is asynchronous in nature so  -

```
const handlerFunction = () => {
  setX(x+1)
  setY(x+1) // here the old value of x will be taken and the outcome value of x and y     will be different //                   
}
```

Here -

```
const [x, setX] = useState(0)
const [y, setY] = useState(x) // this is just to initialize an initial value to your state y so it will be once set to the value of x and then it doesn't depends on x//

const handlerFunction = () => {
  setX(x+1)
  setY(y+1)
}
```