# associate a state with another state in useState hook

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I want to have a state B that its value is dependent to sate A and when state A value updated, state B value updates subsequently.

The problem is as @Atin Singh stated here [changing multiple states in react js useState() hook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59344747/changing-multiple-states-in-react-js-usestate-hook)

```
const [x, setX] = useState(0)
const [y, setY] = useState(x) // this is just to initialize an initial value to your state y so it will be once set to the value of x and then it doesn't depends on x//
```

State B value initialized to state A value and doesn't depends on value of state A.

But is there any way to make state B value dependent on state A value?

Here is the simplified code:

```
export default function App() {
  const [a, setA] = useState("");
  const [b, setB] = useState(a);

  const updateA = () => {
    setA("Hi");
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("a: ", a);
    console.log("b: ", b);
  });

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={updateA}>Update State A</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

you can edit the code from here:
https://codesandbox.io/s/nifty-sun-ml843?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Answer (score 8):

you can use useEffect with Dependency as [a]. Add this block, so when ever `a` gets updated , this useEffect will run and set the value of B

```
   useEffect(() => {
        setB(a);
      },[a]);
```

**complete Code:**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [a, setA] = useState("");
  const [b, setB] = useState(a);

  const updateA = () => {
    setA("Hi");
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    setB(a);
  },[a]);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("a: ", a);
    console.log("b: ", b);
  });

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={updateA}>Update State A</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**Output:**

```
a:  "" 
b:  "" 
a:  Hi 
b:  "" 
a:  Hi 
b:  Hi
```

Comment: Wouldn't this result in a loop ? Since he needs both state to update subsequently. B updates A, then your effect with deps is triggered and update B, then B updates A etc.

Comment: That's right but it re-evaluate whole of state B value each time state A value changed. For example lets think state `B = A + "World"`, I want to recalculate only A part.

Comment: No it will not get into loop, OP wants  state of  B dependent of A  and not both wise. This usestate will be called additionally after value of a is set

Answer (score 3):

If `b` is fully derived from `a` and doesn't need to be set separately you can use `useMemo` hook:

```
import React, { useState, useMemo, useEffect } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [a, setA] = useState("");
  const b = useMemo(() => a, [a]);

  const updateA = () => {
    setA(`Hi, time is ${new Date()}`);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("a: ", a);
    console.log("b: ", b);
  });

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={updateA}>Update State A</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```